# WCF Data Services or WebAPI

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-data-services, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to both technologies and I've been reading about them and started 2 simple projects. The reason for this exercise is to try to understand which technology better suites my needs. The application is as follows:

- Intranet application
- Client application is installed on an 'application' server and users use remote desktop to connect to the 'server' machine
- About 50 concurrent users (on the same 'application' server)
- Model uses Entity Framework 6
- Model has 250+ main entities, many of them complex
- All entities must support CRUD
- Many entities need to support further custom methods
- Auditing of all entity's modified properties (audit records saved in db)
- Long-running tasks executed on server (eg. batch processing, file creation... could take up to 30mins depending on workload), client must be periodically notified (through events?)
- Performance is a priority

So, as an example, I have consumed a WCF service like this:

```
    private void SaveCustomer()
    {
        try
        {
            var ctx = new DBContext(new Uri(Constants.ServerURI));
            var c = new Customer()
            {
                Number = 3,
                Name = "John",
                Surname = "Smith"
            };
            ctx.AddToCustomer(c);
            DataServiceResponse resp = ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //catch exception
        }
    }
```

However, I do not want to expose the dbcontext to the client. Is it possible to implement repository pattern in WCF project?

Also, I do not want to have 1 service and hundreds of methods in it. When I'm working with a customer, I would like to create a customer instance and then use a customer service to commit to db.

From the above points, which technology is better suited?

Comment: I don't have answers to all of your questions because I haven't used WebAPI but I came across this nice blog post regarding not exposing your dbcontext via WCF Data Services (http://thomassmets.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/wcf-data-services-dont-generate-that-reference/)

Comment: Also, consider that you don't have to create one huge entity model, you can split it into separate logical models, possibly one for each repository and then expose each one through its own service or api.